# GNOME Shell Battery Icon missing

Tags: battery, gnome

I am just wondering..... Why is there no battery icon? It's hard to work without any battery status around.

I am using Maverick, and the GNOME3 files came from git.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to "Power Management" and over to the "General" tab, and make sure something other than "Never display an icon" is chosen.

[image: Power Management Window]

Comment: gnome-shell doesn't use the notification area applet any more, so the preferences in that old GNOME 2 dialog won't have any effect as long as you're running gnome-shell rather than gnome-panel.

The control center is being rewritten for GNOME 3, and the plan for gnome-shell is certainly to have a battery indicator, so I'd imagine it just hasn't been implemented yet: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Design/Guidelines/SystemStatus/BatteryPower

Comment: That probably applies to unity as well which also has no notification area

Comment: it doesn't use it in the standard way, but icons still show up. I can test this to confirm, but this fix *might* work